# bounds of integration for marginal pdf

Tags: calculus, integration, statistics

I have the joint pdf:

$f(x, y) = 1/(1-x)$

For $0<x<y<1$

I need to find the marginal pdf of $y$. Would my bounds of integration go from $[0, 1]$ or $[0,y]$? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Think about the value that the pdf assumes when $x \ge y$.

Comment: Since the Question mentions $x \lt y$, it seems odd to suggest focusing on "when $x \ge y$".  One line posts rarely make good answers, and it would appear that Readers would find details about finding "the marginal pdf of $y$" helpful.

Comment: @hardmath well, the way I’d think about it is to just calculate $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,y) \, \mathrm{d} x$, which is I believe a standard definition of the marginal pdf of $y$. That requires thinking about what $f$ is as $x$ varies over $\mathbb R$. Granted, perhaps this way of thinking about it is still odd, but I was hoping it would still help.

Comment: So how do you answer the question posed: do bounds of integration go from $[0,1]$ or $[0,y]$?

Comment: Well, using (a minor extension of) my hint with the integral I give in my previous comment should give the answer, no? I mean, either one of us could just give the exact answer, but I was trying to construct a hint that would help the OP figure out the answer on their own. If you have a better hint, you should post (or even comment) it so I can give it an upvote.